# Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and $A \subset X$. If $x_n$ is a sequence that converges in $A$, then show that it converges in $X$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and $A \subset X$. If $x_n$ is a sequence that converges in $A$, then show that it converges in $X$.

If $x_n \to x$ in $A$, then there exists $K \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n > K$ we have that $x_n \in B(x,r)$ for $r > 0$. Since $x_n \in B(x,r) \subset A \subset X$, we have that $x_n$ converges in $X$.

Is this a valid solution? The problem didn’t seem hard, but I’m not sure that this simple logic is enough to show this?

Comment: As written is not entirely correct. It should rather be $x_n\in B(x,r)\cap A$... but then indeed $x_n\in B(x,r)$ for all $n$ and the claim follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true that $B(x,r) \subset A$. But you don't need that.  Convergence just says that for any $\varepsilon>0$ we can find $N \in \Bbb N$ so that

$$\forall n \ge N: d(x_n, x) < \varepsilon$$

and the same $d$ is used for $A$ and $X$. So the same $N$ works for both.
The fact that we have convergence in $A$ is only because if $x_n \in A$ for all $n$ and $x \in A$ too. The convergence condition itself is the same.